# C# Constant Array Search

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I'm trying to search a string or object in an array and I am aware of the dictionary method. For now, what I'm doing is like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> _usedStrings;
```

and when checking if the string exists

```
_usedStrings.ContainsKey("key");
```

This way, the checking will always be constant. Is there a way I can achieve constant searching without the use of a dictionary?

Comment: Can you explain why you *want* to avoid using a dictionary here? It's the most obvious approach, so what makes you want to do something different?

Comment: The value from key, value pair is not used, just wondering if there are any other approaches.

Comment: You could use a `List<string>` to achieve this then use its`.Contains` method

Comment: Not completely sure what you're trying to achieve but `HashSet<T>` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Knoop, I found it too just now upon digging into different types of collection in c#

Comment: I'm blocked from answering questions but this is where I found the answer: https://programmingwithmosh.com/net/csharp-collections/

Comment: For your use case, `HashSet<>` is much better than `List<>` in terms of performance.

Comment: Specify the requirements for the collection. What do you need: quick search, add, insert, delete? | You can use BinarySearch for arrays and lists with complexity O (log n) if they are sorted.

Comment: The dictionary is effective on large amounts of data. On small amounts, it has a large overhead. For example, see [HybridDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.hybriddictionary?view=net-5.0)

Comment: There are many techniques to speed up array/list iteration. From [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) and [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to parallelization.